# How to read a Json inside a Json in java?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to get the data of this Json. As you can see the first element have a json inside of the json.

```
{
   "client":{
      "colour":"aabb11",
      "height":200,
      "xpos":0,
      "packages":"com.samsung.incallUi",
      "events":[
         {
            "action":"hide",
            "class":"com.android.TextView",
            "type":"2"
         },
         {
            "colour":"00FF00",
            "action":"show"
         }
      ],
      "width":600,
      "ypos":20
   },
   "Map":" {red=blue, yellow=brown}",
   "Country":"IT"
}
```

I get the json from:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(INIT_URL).post(formBody).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I'm trying this, but don't work (give me an JsonSyntaxException):

```
...
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

    String client = jo.getString("client");
    String xpos = jo.getString("height");
    String packages = jo.getString("xpos");
    String events = jo.getString("packages");
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: `{"client":...}` is not a JSON array ...

Comment: The JSON object it's corrupt... post your real JSON response....

Comment: Post your total response.

Comment: Sorry, now the JSON is correct. I edit my question @aspicas

Comment: This is my total response @manikanta

Comment: What do you mean: "I'm trying this, but don't work"? Are you getting an error/exception? The question is vague.

Comment: You should use a [Json Tree Viewer](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) and you will see how to parse it.

Comment: @Rob I edit my question. Give me a JsonSyntaxException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element, "client" is an object not an array.
try

```
JSONObject ja= new JSONObject(response.body().string());
```

Comment: Yes, but only can read the first element client. When go to map I get a JsonSyntaxException

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look into a JSON parser, such us [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Will do your life much easier.

```
//Jackson example
Client client = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Client.class);
```

Just define your Client class with the fields in the JSON

Comment: I've tried with Gson, but I can't get the first element "clientconfig". If I do the request with this element, works...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using `Gson`.  If you can't get it right with gson, that means, your model is not correct. If you have a hard time creating the model for the json, you can [auto generate the model](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) instead of creating it your self.